# Colorize files in SublimeText tree-view based on git status?

Tags: git, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I love sublimeText, use it everyday since a year now. There is a feature I am looking for : **in my list of files (left panel), I would like to colorizes folders and files that are untracked, ignored, and modified.**

This feature is part of Atom but I am surprise not having anything like this in Sublime. I already us "*Git Config*", "*GitGutter*" and "*GitSavvy*".

Here is an exemple of what I am trying to have :

[image: colorizes folders and files that are untracked, ignored, and modified]

Has anyone ever heard of such thing ? I actually started to doubt if it is possible to color those ? may be that's why ? Anyone ever seen a package doing a similar feature ?

Thanks for reading/helping ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently no sidebar API in Sublime that would allow for this. It has been requested, but no guarantees as to whether it will make it into a future release of Sublime Text 3, or whether the author has marked it for ST4 (which he is working on).

Comment: There is an issue for it at the unofficial issue tracker. I'm not sure that tracker is prioritized by Jon, but adding your +1 to the issue could potentially help :/ https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/867

Comment: @Albin Jon and Will Bond (the other core Sublime developer, of Package Control fame) are certainly well aware of the issue tracker and use it in part to guide their work. There are a lot of feature requests out there, but I know a sidebar API is pretty high up there, so hopefully one will be released soon.